maven-javadoc-plugin does not work correctly in conjunction with hibernate-jpa-modelgen
I am faced with the problem that I am getting an error:

Exit code: 1
C:\Users*\Desktop***\target\delombok\ru**\service\impl*.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
import ru...entity.Balance_;
^
symbol:   class Balance_
location: package ru...entity
1 error
Command line was: cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\javadoc.exe" @options @argfile"
Refer to the generated Javadoc files in 'C:\Users*\Desktop*\repositories*\target\apidocs' dir.

and here is a description of how to reproduce this problem:

Adding codegen dependencies

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.32</version>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
    <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
    <version>6.4.4.Final</version>
</dependency>


Adding the maven-javadoc-plugin and maven-compiler-plugin plugins (to add annotationProcessorPaths to it)

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                <version>6.4.4.Final</version>
            </path>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>1.18.32</version>
            </path>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.5.Final</version>
            </path>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                <version>0.2.0</version>
            </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
        <compilerArgs>
            <compilerArg>
                -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring
            </compilerArg>
        </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>


Done. Next, we use these models anywhere in the code. For example, just output a static model field to the log log.info(String.valueOf(Balance_.id)); and when trying to make mvn clean package, an error will be received. What am I doing wrong?

I've tried literally all the tips on the Internet and still can't figure out how to tie it all together...
